# Ubuntu doesnt show unallocated partition but rather the whole NTFS partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mbr, gpt

First of all the disk doesnt show as primary in Windows Disk Managment when I try to split a certain partition but rather simple volume. When I split the partition, I can allocate to NTFS as easy as it sounds. However when I try to allocate using the Ubuntu installation, I can only see the whole partitiom that I split to two as NTFS and not the new partition I created as free space.

The laptop had Windows 8 installed in it, and upgraded to Win10. I believe the disk is GPT and not MBR.

How do I solve this problem? Without having to format/lose data.

Comment: Unallocated space is not a partition. Can you please post a screenshot of GParted (run in a live session). Also please give more details about what you intend to do, what are the expected results and you get instead.

Comment: You may be misinterpreting the display, as CelticWarrior suggests; or you may have accidentally created a [Logical Disk Manager (LDM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager) setup, which is incompatible with Ubuntu installation. A screen shot, as CelticWarrior suggests, should clarify the matter.